# Why do function pointers not name their arguments?

Tags: c, function, pointers

For example, a function gives a name to its arguments

```
int add(int x,int y){
    // Code
}
```

However a pointer to the same function does not use names like 'x' or 'y'

```
int (*add)(int,int)
```

Why don't pointers to functions also name the parameters like this?

```
int (*add)(int x,int y)
```

Comment: You can write `int (*add)(int x,int y);`. The decision to use parameter names is up to you, the coder.  Your question is framed strangely, the coder makes the decisions , not the function pointer.

Comment: I suggest to change the title to "Why don't function prototypes need formal parameter names?" The obvious answer also is: When you cannot refer to the parameters, you don't need to name them.

Answer (score 4):

The parameters in a function pointer don’t need names because they aren’t used.  Only the definition of a function requires names for the parameters.

Note that this also means that a function declaration doesn’t need to name its parameters.

```
int add( int, int );
```

Answer (score 2):

Because there's no need and no use for the names, so they're optional.  But you *can* include them if you like (they're certainly not forbidden), and it might be useful to give the arguments names in order to make it clearer how the arguments will be used.

Exactly the same rules apply to function prototypes.  Argument names are optional there, too, but it's often recommended to use names so that the prototype can serve as sort of mini-documentation for the function.

(Finally, by comparison, in C++, argument names are optional even in function/method definitions, if for whatever reason the arguments aren't used at all.)

Comment: Regarding the last paragraph, I think there's some indication that C2x will make the same change in C and allow it.